# How do I put this data into third normal form?

Tags: database-design, 3nf

Here is my image of three entities, with ORDER and PRODUCT having many-to-many relationships:

[image: My three entities]

I understand that I have to remove transitive dependencies to turn it from 2NF to 3NF. Does this mean I need to create an associative table between ORDER and PRODUCT with OrderID and ProductID as composite keys, and OrderQuantity as an attribute?

Do I have to do the same thing with CustomerPONumber (which is an attribute created by the customer themselves to keep track of their order and kept on their system)?

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. PS "I have to remove transitive dependencies" No. You have to transform to a design that doesn't have certain kinds of transitive FDs.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please ask just 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are in 3NF as far as I can see, only that there is no relation between orders and products, yet :-)

Yes, add a table to relate order and product just as you describe.

The CustomerPONumber seems to be in the correct place already. (It's rather easy to see this: you won't store the same number twice, so there is no redundancy, which is what normalization is about mostly.)